# Data is not displaying in Angular2 App from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I linked my angular 2 app on Stackblitz editor. Successfully linked but the data is neither being displayed in the console nor in the browser. Please help me how can I display the data using angularfire2 latest version.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebasedemo-angunv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it wrong in html

try this

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of items | async">
      {{course}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

you are getting data async, to console log your data you need to subscribe to it

```
this.items.subscribe(courses => {
    courses.forEach(course => {
        console.log(course);
    }
});
```